# NSTableCellView in MonoMac

Tags: monomac

I'm fairly new to MonoMac and I am trying to figure out if the `NSTableCellView` class ([shown here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableCellView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) is available in MonoMac?

I see there is an `NSTableViewCell` class in MonoMac, but that seems to be completely different.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class in question is not currently part of the [available Mono APIs](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=root%3a). You may be able to get access to this type by [creating a binding to the underlying Objective-C API](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types).